# getting errors output with razzle

Tags: reactjs, razzle

I am using razzle for my react js app. when I run razzle start --verbose I get

✖ Client
Compiled with some errors in 4.88s

✖ Server
Compiled with some errors in 1.46s

I do not however get what the errors are.I have tried to find a way to get errors to be revealed but have had no luck.

Does anyone know how to configure so that you actually get the errors output?

Answer (score 0):

What has helped me before is to do `npm run build` or `razzle build`, which usually means I missed an import.